# How to confirm $\lim_{s\to0} \frac{\zeta(1-s)}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})} = -\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the functional equation $$\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s)=\pi^{-\frac{1-s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1-s}{2})\zeta(1-s)$$
I am supposed to calcualte $\zeta(0)$. I can write this as
$$\zeta(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\lim_{s\to0}\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{\Gamma(s/2)}$$
an I have to write the limit there, because numerator and denominator both have a pole of order 1. Therefore I also know that this limit exists, but unfortunately I am unable to evaluate it.
I looked up several identities for $\zeta(s)$ and $\Gamma(s)$ in my textbook and tried to evaluate any of the resulting limits. Most of the times I was only able to confirm that the limit exists, e.g. that the resulting integrals converge, but I was never able to evaluate it. (I mean I know its $-\frac{1}{2}$, but it is not about the result but about understanding how to evaluate this limit.)

I'd appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: The limit is the ratio of the residues and the top one is $-1$ as $\zeta(1-s)$ behaves like $-1/s$ near zero and the bottom one is $2$ since $\Gamma(s)$ behaves like, $1/s$ near zero so $\Gamma(s/2)$ behaves like $2/s$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeta function has a simple pole at $s=1$ with residue $1$ (eg a proof is in Ahlfors), while the Gamma function has a simple pole at $s=0$ with residue $1$ (follows from the equation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(1)=1$).

So, we can write
\begin{align}
\zeta(1-s)&=\frac{1}{-s}+\alpha(s)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)&=\frac{1}{s/2}+\beta(s)=\frac{2}{s}+\beta(s)
\end{align}
for some functions $\alpha,\beta$ which are in fact holomorphic in a neighborhood of the origin. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\zeta(s)&=\pi^{s-\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\\
&=\pi^{s-\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\frac{-1+s\alpha(s)}{2+s\beta(s)}
\end{align}
Now, by letting $s\to 0$, we see that $\zeta(0)=\pi^{-1/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{-1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}$.